# Arquillian RESTful Web Service Test - URL error

Tags: java, maven, junit, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I'm doing some integration tests for a REST API I developed. I'm trying to use `Arquillian` but I can't seem to find that much information about tests on `RESTful webservices`. I just want to test that my API returns the right String. It's a currency converter, we give an input like `"USD/10/EUR"` and it converts, returning a String like `"10 USD -> 8.21827744904668 EUR"`.

Right now, this is where I'm at with the test class:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ExchangeRateTest {

@Deployment(testable = false)
public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
        .addPackage(ExchangeRate.class.getPackage())
        .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
}    

@ArquillianResource
private URL base;

private static WebTarget target;

@Before
public void setUpClass() throws MalformedURLException {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    target = client.target(URI.create(new URL(base, "webresources/rates/USD/10/EUR").toExternalForm()));
}

@Test
@RunAsClient
public void testResponse(@ArquillianResource URL base) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    try {
        System.out.println("URL TARGET: " + target.getUri().toURL().toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //assertEquals("10 USD -> 8.21827744904668 EUR", target.request().get().readEntity(String.class));
}

}
```

The following error appears:

```
Could not lookup value for field private java.net.URL com.mycompany.tqshw.ExchangeRateTest.base java.lang.RuntimeException at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.enrich(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:71) at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:55) at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.ClientTestInstanceEnricher.enrich(ClientTestInstanceEnricher.java:51) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81) at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142) at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88) at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88) at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88) at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116) at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.before(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:108) at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:241) at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:426) at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54) at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:259) at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:319) at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.execute(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:99) at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.on(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:72) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81) at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142) at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88) at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:130) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88) at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88) at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145) at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116) at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.fireCustomLifecycle(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:159) at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:312) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:204) at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:426) at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54) at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:218) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:166) at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53) at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123) at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164) at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110) at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175) at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107) at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for type class java.net.URL returned a null value: org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.enricher.resource.URLResourceProvider@3d246ea3 at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.lookup(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:133) at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.enrich(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:67) ... 114 more
```

This is my RESTful Webservice:

```
@Path("rates")
public class ExchangeRate {
private final CurrencyCalculator rates;

public ExchangeRate() {
    rates = new CurrencyCalculator();
}

@GET
@Path("{from}/{amount}/{to}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getRates(@PathParam("from") String from,@PathParam("amount") 
    String amount, @PathParam("to") String to) {
    double value = 0;
    try{
        value = rates.convert(from, Double.parseDouble(amount), to);
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        System.err.println("Currency is not available.");
    }        
    return amount+" "+from+" -> "+value+" "+to;
}
}
```

I'd be more than happy if you could point me out my mistakes with the Test Class.

Comment: Have you tried to create a war, put it on your AS and try it to know if there is a problem on your code or in Arquillian? Also which application server are you using? Can you provide a GitHub link to the project?

Comment: Also notice that `@RunAsClient` and `testResponse(@ArquillianResource URL base)` is not necessary.

Comment: I ended up redoing the entire class and providing the complete URL with parameters withouth the @ArquillianResource.